# How I can create a PointField using an api?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using django-rest-framework for the API, but when I make a post request sends me this error:

```
{
    "location": [
        "Invalid format: string or unicode input unrecognized as GeoJSON, WKT EWKT or HEXEWKB."
    ]
}
```

Body request:

```
{
    "location":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[37.0625,-95.677068]
    }
}
```

My model is as follows:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    location = geo.PointField(srid=4326, blank=True)
    objects = geo.GeoManager()
```

My serializer is a follow:

```
class AddressCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ('location')
```

Help me please!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I use [`PointField`](https://github.com/Hipo/drf-extra-fields#pointfield) from `django-extra-fields` for this. Supernice and intuitive for frontend developers (I write mobile backends mostly). With that, in your serializer specify:

```
from drf_extra_fields.geo_fields import PointField

class AddressCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    location = PointField()

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ('location')
```

Request (taking a guess as to which of your values is lat and which is lon):

```
{
    "location":{
        "latitude": 37.0625
        "longitude": -95.677068,
    }
}
```

Comment: Production is heroku

Comment: Problem solved. On the server the GEOS library is not installed. Still thanks for your answer man