# Why doesn't Django Rest Framwork show the posted latitude?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I've got a Django code base which uses [Django Rest Framework (DRF)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) for an API which serves the contents of the DB to the frontend.

I now also want users to be able to post new content through this API. I got the API to accept POSTs, but I've got trouble with a [gis Pointfield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#pointfield).

In one of my models I've got the following field:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models

class Device(models.Model):
    geometry = gis_models.PointField(name='geometry', null=True, blank=True)
    # And some other fields
```

I let people post the geometry in two separate fields (`latitude` and `longitude`) which I then want to write to the `geometry` field. I've got a DeviceSerializer which looks like this:

class DeviceSerializer(HALSerializer):
    types = TypeSerializer(many=True)
    longitude = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    latitude = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    organisation = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

```
class Meta:
    model = Device
    fields = (
        '_links',
        'id',
        'types',
        'longitude',
        'latitude',
        'organisation'
    )

def get_organisation(self, obj):
    if obj.owner:
        return obj.owner.organisation
    return 'Unknown'

def get_longitude(self, obj):
    if obj.geometry:
        return obj.geometry.x

def get_latitude(self, obj):
    if obj.geometry:
        return obj.geometry.y

def create(self, validated_data):
    print(validated_data)  # IN HERE I DON'T RECEIVE THE POSTED LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE

    types_data = validated_data.pop('types')
    device = Device.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for type_data in types_data:
        Type.objects.create(device=device, **type_data)

    if 'longitude' in validated_data and 'latitude' in validated_data:
        # WE NEVER REACH THIS POINT BECAUSE THE LAT AND LONG ARE NEVER POSTED
        device.geometry = Point(validated_data.pop('longitude'), validated_data.pop('latitude'))

    return device
```

In my test I then do this:

```
response = self.client.post(
    url,
    data={'types': [], 'latitude': 1, 'longitude': 1, 'organisation': 'abc'},
    format='json'
)
```

But the `latitude` and `longitude` never show up in the `print(validated_data)`. Does anybody know why they are missing there?

Comment: In the model you spell it `geometry`, but in the serializer its `geometrie`, could it be this?

Comment: @KathyRindhoops - No that is not it. That was just an edit mistake, since I translated some fields. Thanks for the heads up though, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

The solution below is not as clean as many other solutions, such as the one given in this answer [How I can create a PointField using an api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186522/how-i-can-create-a-pointfield-using-an-api) . I would recommend using this one, but will leave mine below for others if needed

---

The problem is that you are sending the `latitude` and `longitude` in the data but the model only has a field called geometry. I see you are trying to set this using the validated data, but validated data is data checked against the fields of the model so you won't be able to get it here. One way around this would be to add a context in the View.

if your view was something like:

```
class MyView():
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(
            data=request.data,
            context={
                "latitude": request.data.get('latitude')
                "longitude": request.data.get('longitude')
            },
        )
        if serializer.is_valid:
            serilazer.save()
```

Then in the serializer you could override the `validate` function with

```
def validate(self, attrs):
    latitude = self.context.get("latitude")
    longitude = self.context.get("longitude")
    attrs.update(
        {
            "geometry": Point(latitude, longitude)
        }
    )
    return super().validate(attrs)
```

Comment: Another possible answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186522/how-i-can-create-a-pointfield-using-an-api

Comment: I first tried your solution here, but that got me in all sorts of new trouble. The solution in the link is works perfect though AND is super clean. Maybe you can add the link to the answer so that it get's more attention to future readers?
Oh, and noti